# Can we create two website with the same code and database

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, hosting, virtualhost

Requirement is to create two website

- www.example1.com
- www.example2.com

with the same codebase and database without copying it to another directory or importing the sql file.

Is it possible through just pointing it based on domain name and using .htaccess file.

Any help or hints is appreciated.

Comment: Yes. If you're using Apache, just create a second virtual directory and point that to the same folder.

Comment: If you want both sites 100% identical then yes, you can. Just point the document root to the same directory for both sites in your Apache configuration file. But without knowing what this condensate looks like, it's hard to predict what issues you'll encounter. You might need to change all the absolute links to relative. If it's s CMS it might store the URL in the database and redirect to what it thinks is the"right" one. Making it work like this might end up being harder than just making a second instance of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. Start by placing all of your project files on the same directory, for the sake of this example let's call it `/var/www/example`

Then go to `/etc/apache2/sites-available` and create two `.conf` files:

- `example1.conf`: Virtual Host Configuration for www.example1.com
- `example2.conf`: Virtual Host Configuration for www.example2.com

The contents of the two configuration files:

**example1.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/example"
    ServerName www.example1.com


</VirtualHost>
```

**exampl2.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/example"
        ServerName www.example2.com


</VirtualHost>
```

As you can see both of them refer the same directory as Document Root but listen to different URLs.

After you're done creating those files don't forget to run the following commands on your terminal:
 `a2ensite example1.conf`

`a2ensite example2.conf`

and finally,

```
service apache2 reload
```